# Powering Hokuyo from Kobuki

Tags: turtlebot, kobuki, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I recently purchased a Hokuyo UST 10LX, and i'm having a difficult time figuring out how to get power from the Kobuki (Turtlebot 2) to the scanner. There are a few posts on here about getting the software to work with Hokuyo, but i'm still stuck on the hardware side of things! Do we need to connect the +VIN and -VIN to a 12v supply on Turtlebot?  If anyone could shed some light / share their knowledge I would greatly appreciate it!

Link to info about each wire in power cord:
http://www.hokuyo-aut.jp/02sensor/07scanner/ust_10lx_20lx.html

Detailed Picture of connector:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Uzsg5R6AysbV9taTFIV25KZ1A1TThwdFNzZUQxMWhpcmo4/view?usp=sharing

Size of connector:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Uzsg5R6AysT0VUUzI3cHVzMEYzbnlDaFVSS01lR0hUNkFj/view?usp=sharing
Thank you for your time!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211935/powering-hokuyo-from-kobuki/) by [fantasticmsfo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22893/fantasticmsfo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The cable wiring is as follows:
Red: COM Input +
Gray: COM Output -
Light Blue: IP Reset Input
Orange: Synchronous Output
Brown +VIN (12VDC / 24VDC)
Blue: -VIN
Since I plan on using the Ethernet connection for communication, I only need to connect the brown and blue cables for power.

---

Originally posted by [fantasticmsfo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22893/fantasticmsfo/) with karma: 21 on 2015-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2